# Wordpress blog post tags in 2 rows

Tags: posts, tags, conditional-tags, template-tags

In the WordPress theme I use, I can usually add 5-6 tags in one blog post.

If I add more tags (7, 8, etc...), the tags continue to go under the sidebar, and don't make a second row (what usually the WP themes do).

So, obviously the tags don't follow the width of the blog content area (~ 800 pixels).
(The title, categories, and blog content / text - are OK.)

Can I fix this issue with CSS or else?

I can share the code of these sections (categories, tags...) if necessary.